# Upload file to google drive fails

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Upload a file from android to Google drive is failing. Seems like the `createFile` is not working even the status returned is success. The actual status error code and message that I get from the Google API is error code 8, error message: **Provided DriveId is not valid**

I also cannot find the file on the related user Google drive (using web interface for the Google drive).

I have also tried using `Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(m_api, m_file.getDriveId().toString())` in the create file callback (instead of calling to `openContents`), and it has also failed.

Related code is below, any help would be appreciated!

```
public void createFile() {
  Drive.DriveApi.newContents(m_api).setResultCallback(contentsCallback);
}

final private ResultCallback<ContentsResult> contentsCallback = new ResultCallback<ContentsResult>() {
  @Override
  public void onResult(ContentsResult result) {
    if (handleError(result.getStatus())) {
      return;
    }

    Contents contents = result.getContents();
    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
        .setTitle("aaab").setMimeType("text/plain")
        .setStarred(true).build();

    // create a file on root folder
    Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(m_api)
        .createFile(m_api, changeSet, contents)
        .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
  }

};

final private ResultCallback<DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveFileResult>() {
  @Override
  public void onResult(DriveFileResult result) {
    if (handleError(result.getStatus())) {
      return;
    }
    m_file = result.getDriveFile();

    m_file.openContents(m_api, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null)
        .setResultCallback(updateCallback);
  }
};

final private ResultCallback<ContentsResult> updateCallback = new ResultCallback<ContentsResult>() {
  @Override
  public void onResult(ContentsResult result) {
    // Getting error here
    if (handleError(result.getStatus())) {
      return;
    }

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it!
It had 2 problems:

First issue is my fault - my android manifest was missing APP_ID for drive services:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

Second, the activity was extending predefined Google class: BaseGameActivity.
But this class assumes the I am not using Google drive files. To make it work, I had to add this in my Activity:

```
    mRequestedClients = GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL;
```

and change Google predefined code. Actually it looks like a bug in google, assuming google APP folder is always used, and not Google drive files. In GameHelper.java, line 298, from:

```
builder.addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER);
```

to:

```
builder.addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK problem is that new file is not created.
for creating new file on GoogleDrive i use this code and work fine, problem is in your googleapiclient or i don't know where and how you call your funct createFile(). You must call in onConnected metode.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);
    // create new contents resource
    Drive.DriveApi.newContents(m_api)
            .setResultCallback(contentsCallback);
}

final private ResultCallback<ContentsResult> contentsCallback = new
        ResultCallback<ContentsResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(ContentsResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Error while trying to create new file contents");
            return;
        }

        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                .setTitle("New file")
                .setMimeType("text/plain")
                .setStarred(true).build();
        // create a file on root folder
        Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(m_api)
                .createFile(m_api, changeSet, result.getContents())
                .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
    }
};

final private ResultCallback<DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveFileResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveFileResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Error while trying to create the file");
            return;
        }
        showMessage("Created a file: " + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId());
    }
};
```

Comment: The `fileCallback` is success, and the getStatus().isSuccess() is true. However, it seems that the file is not being created as I cannot see it in the Google drive. Also next commands that try handling the file such as `openContents` and `fetchDriveId` return error for accessing the file